# Laravel diacritic insensitive search

Tags: php, regex, laravel, full-text-search

I try to make an API which accepts a Query params to filter the results within the following link `api/results/search?somefield=er`. Results I'm expecting should be for example:

- litt**ér**ature
- réalis**er**
- procur**er**
- alt**ér**ée

In short, actual version of Google Chrome have exactly what I need, when you press `CTRL+F` in Google Chrome and try to search for `er` on this page https://fr.lipsum.com/ you will get a full-text-search with highlights of `ér` and `er`.

I'm using a Laravel Collection instead of Eloquent.

To make a search case insesitive, PHP already have a function for this case called [stristr($haystack, $needle)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

```
foreach (request()->except('perPage') as $key => $value) {
    $results = $results->filter(function ($item) use ($key, $value) {
        return false !== stristr($item->$key, $value);
    });
}
```

Now I'm stucked at the point, on how to properly search for diacritic letters (french/spanish/etc. accents).

I have already made a list of characters, but have no clue how to use code it.

```
return [
    'siblings' => [
        'A'  => ['À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Å', 'Ǻ', 'Ā', 'Ă', 'Ą', 'Ǎ', 'Α', 'Ά', 'Ả', 'Ạ', 'Ầ', 'Ẫ', 'Ẩ', 'Ậ', 'Ằ', 'Ắ', 'Ẵ', 'Ẳ', 'Ặ', 'А'],
        'B'  => ['B'],
        'C'  => ['Ç', 'Ć', 'Ĉ', 'Ċ', 'Č'],
        'D'  => ['Ð', 'Ď', 'Đ', 'Δ'],
        'E'  => ['È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ē', 'Ĕ', 'Ė', 'Ę', 'Ě', 'Ε', 'Έ', 'Ẽ', 'Ẻ', 'Ẹ', 'Ề', 'Ế', 'Ễ', 'Ể', 'Ệ', 'Е', 'Э'],
        'F'  => ['ƒ'],
        'G'  => ['Ĝ', 'Ğ', 'Ġ', 'Ģ'],
        'H'  => ['Ĥ', 'Ħ'],
        'I'  => ['Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ĩ', 'Ī', 'Ĭ', 'Ǐ', 'Į', 'İ', 'Η', 'Ή', 'Ί', 'Ι', 'Ϊ', 'Ỉ', 'Ị'],
        'J'  => ['Ĵ'],
        'K'  => ['Ķ', 'Κ', 'К'],
        'L'  => ['Ĺ', 'Ļ', 'Ľ', 'Ŀ', 'Ł', 'Λ', 'Л'],
        'M'  => [''],
        'N'  => ['Ñ', 'Ń', 'Ņ', 'Ň', 'Ν'],
        'O'  => ['Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ō', 'Ŏ', 'Ǒ', 'Ő', 'Ơ', 'Ø', 'Ǿ', 'Ο', 'Ό', 'Ω', 'Ώ', 'Ỏ', 'Ọ', 'Ồ', 'Ố', 'Ỗ', 'Ổ', 'Ộ', 'Ờ', 'Ớ', 'Ỡ', 'Ở', 'Ợ', 'О'],
        'P'  => [''],
        'R'  => ['Ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'Ř'],
        'S'  => ['Ś', 'Ŝ', 'Ş', 'Ș', 'Š', 'Σ'],
        'T'  => ['Ț', 'Ţ', 'Ť', 'Ŧ', 'Τ', 'Т'],
        'U'  => ['Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ũ', 'Ū', 'Ŭ', 'Ů', 'Ű', 'Ų', 'Ư', 'Ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'Ủ', 'Ụ', 'Ừ', 'Ứ', 'Ữ', 'Ử', 'Ự'],
        'X'  => [''],
        'Y'  => ['Ý', 'Ÿ', 'Ŷ', 'Υ', 'Ύ', 'Ϋ', 'Ỳ', 'Ỹ', 'Ỷ', 'Ỵ'],
        'W'  => ['Ŵ'],
        'Z'  => ['Ź', 'Ż', 'Ž', 'Ζ'],
        'AE' => ['Ä', 'Æ', 'Ǽ'],
        'UE' => ['Ü'],
        'IJ' => ['Ĳ'],
        'OE' => ['Ö', 'Œ'],
        'TH' => ['þ'],
        'SS' => ['ß'],
        'KS' => ['ξ'],
    ]
];
```

I would highly appreciate if someone can give me a point what approach should I use. I believe I need to use a [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but maybe there is a more simple way similiar to `stristr()` ?

thanks for any given idea.

Comment: I have no answer to you question, but i can show an another option. So what about [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to make your own list Laravel has a method called `Str::ascii` which would convert non-ascii characters to their ascii equivalent so you'd do:

```
foreach (request()->except('perPage') as $key => $value) {
    $results = $results->filter(function ($item) use ($key, $value) {
        return false !== stristr(\Str::ascii($item->$key), \Str::ascii($value));
    });
}
```

There's also a 2nd parameter in `Str::ascii` for the language although from what I've seen you only need to use it for bg (Bulgarian) or de (German)

If you need to check what the whole list is you can see [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L564) which also mentions that it's based on the [Stringy](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy) library.

Bottom line is don't write your own list unless the ones that already exist are not enough for you.

Note that there's also the option of using `iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $string)` which will transliterate non ascii characters. More info at [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)